# Overload matrix operator

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I'm working on matrix multiplication using Strassen algorithm. I'm trying to overload the ' * ' operator without success. I have low experience in C++ and I don't know how to fix it.

I got no error at runtime, but the Matrix parameter `m` has weard values (8215421532 instead of 4 for example), so the result is false. When I try the `strassen` method in a more classic way (without operator), it works just fine.

Matrix.h

```
class Matrix
{
public:

    int size;
    int** mat;

    Matrix(int n, int** values);
    Matrix(int n, int min, int max);
    virtual ~Matrix();

    void print();

    Matrix multiply(Matrix m);
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix&);
    Matrix operator*(const Matrix&) const;
};
```

Matrix.cpp

```
Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix& m) const {

    if (m.size != size){
        printf("La matrice n'a pas la bonne taille !\n");
        return Matrix(0,NULL);
    }

    int **res = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        res[i] = new int[size];
    }

    // Breakpoint here: variable m seems completely wrong
    strassen(mat, m.mat, res, size);
    return Matrix(size, res);
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& m){
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m.size; j++)
        mat[i][j] = m.mat[i][j];
    return *this;
}
```

main.cpp

```
Matrix m1 = Matrix(4, 0, 9);
Matrix m2 = Matrix(4, 0, 9);

printf("Matrice 1 :\n");
m1.print();
printf("Matrice 2 :\n");
m2.print();

printf("Multiplication Strassen :\n");
Matrix m3 = m1 * m2;
m3.print();
```

By the way, if you see a mistake in the ' = ' operator, do not hesitate to tell me. Thanks for your help, got stuck on this for the past 2 hours...

EDIT:
Matrix constructors code (I don't understand why it's relevant here but I trust you)

```
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int** values)
{
    size = n;

    mat = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        mat[i] = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            mat[i][j] = values[i][j];
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int n, int min, int max)
{
    size = n;

    mat = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        mat[i] = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            mat[i][j] = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

EDIT2: solved by adding copy constructor (rule of three) --> thanks Igor Tandetnik (in comments)

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& m){
    size = m.size;

    mat = new int*[m.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size; i++){
        mat[i] = new int[m.size];
        for (int j = 0; j < m.size; j++)
            mat[i][j] = m.mat[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: The assignment operator doesn't guard against self assignment, you may want to fix that. Also, can you post the code for the Matrix constructor, there is a chance that the bug is in there as the multiplication operator looks pretty reasonable at first glance.

Comment: Here is the code for matrix constructors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)): if your class needs any one of a user-defined copy constructor, copy assignment operator or destructor, most likely it needs all three. You are creating copies of `Matrix` left and right - but there's no copy constructor. So you are using the compiler-generated one, that simply copies `mat` pointer. You end up with multiple `Matrix` instances all pointing to the same data; then one of these instances dies and destroys the data, leaving others holding dangling pointers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you should post an answer

Comment: indeed... I read it but didn't think it was relevant here. Rule of three was the solution and I was searching other ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding copy constructor (rule of three) --> thanks Igor Tandetnik (in comments)

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& m){
    size = m.size;

    mat = new int*[m.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size; i++){
        mat[i] = new int[m.size];
        for (int j = 0; j < m.size; j++)
            mat[i][j] = m.mat[i][j];
    }
}
```